# HTML <ul> tag nog stretching to corners of page

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm in the progress of making a navigation bar using the `<ul>` tag, but I'm running into a problem where the bar doesn't stretch to the edges of the webpage.

[image]

HTML:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#store">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: add `body { margin: 0; }` - The "white-space"  is caused by the default body margin.

Comment: Totally missed that! Thanks, it fixed the problem

Comment: You can easily find out most styling problem causes by simply using your browser's developer tools *inspector* tab. Inspecting the `body` element you'd have seen there's a `margin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original code, I didn't account for the default body margin. I added `body { margin: 0; }` as suggested by user tacoshy, which fixed the unwanted "white-space".